# incorrect frame size when instantiating ViewController w/ xib

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xib

I have a view controller that looks like:

```
class SpotViewController: UIViewController {
  let spot: Spot

  init(spot: Spot) {
    self.spot = spot
    super.init(nibName: "SpotViewController", bundle: nil)
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    print("viewWillAppear: \(view.frame)") # => (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 600.0)
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("viewDidLoad: \(view.frame)") # => (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 600.0)
  }
}
```

When I instantiate the view controller via `let spotViewController = SpotViewController(spot: spot)` and push it onto the navigation controller the resulting frame is incorrect in both `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`. It gives me `(0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 600.0)` which is the size in the interface builder.

Why is this happening and what is the correct way to instantiate a view controller w/ a xib to ensure that the frame is correct?

Comment: How are you showing the controller (view)?

Comment: @Wain I'm just pushing it onto the `navigationController` stack w/ `navigationController!.pushViewController(spotViewController, animated: true)`

Comment: What is the frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews() ?

Comment: @DennisPashkov it's correct (`(0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)`) in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Is this the correct place add things such as adding programmatic elements/constraints?

Comment: No, add them and the layout rules when the view loads / it's appropriate. By view appearing the layout will get organised

Comment: You should decide the correct place for this... Pls consider that 'viewDidLayoutSubviews()' can be called multiple times, so don't add your UI elements twice. And yes, the best solution is to setup all the layout in XIB/storyboard without adding elements programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your issue, UIViewController loaded from xib, keep xib size during viewDidLoad:

```
extension UIViewController {
    public override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }
        if self !== UIViewController.self {
            return
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            pb_applyFixToViewFrameWhenLoadingFromNib()
        }
    }

    @objc func pb_setView(view: UIView!) {
        // View is loaded from xib file
        if nibBundle != nil && storyboard == nil {
            view.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
            view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        pb_setView(view)
    }

    private class func pb_applyFixToViewFrameWhenLoadingFromNib() {
        UIViewController.swizzleMethodSelector(NSSelectorFromString("setView:"), withSelector: #selector(UIViewController.pb_setView(_:)))
        UICollectionView.swizzleMethodSelector(#selector(UICollectionView.layoutSubviews), withSelector: #selector(UICollectionView.pb_layoutSubviews))
        UITableView.swizzleMethodSelector(#selector(UITableView.layoutSubviews), withSelector: #selector(UITableView.pb_layoutSubviews))
    }
}

extension UITableView {
    @objc private func pb_layoutSubviews() {
        if dataSource == nil {
            super.layoutSubviews()
        } else {
            pb_layoutSubviews()
        }
    }
}

extension UICollectionView {
    @objc private func pb_layoutSubviews() {
        if dataSource == nil {
            super.layoutSubviews()
        } else {
            pb_layoutSubviews()
        }
    }
}
```